# Need help in finding multiplier to solve the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following quasi linear partial differential equation, but I am not able to find the appropriate multiplier,

$${dx\over 2y(z-3)}={dy\over 2x-z}={dz\over y(2x-3)}$$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first and last terms:
$$\frac{dx}{2(z-3)}=\frac{dz}{2x-3}$$
or: $$(2x-3)dx=2(z-3)dz$$

Comment: But that would give only one arbitrary constant, what about the other?

Comment: You can solve this problem by finding out $x$ and $z$ first, then it's easy to find $y$. But if you want multiplier method, how about multiplying all equations by $y$, then use $dw=ydy$? Do you think you can solve that problem?